# How to Display Multiple Dynamic Data table using JSF

Tags: jsf, dynamic, datatable

I have already successfully displayed a dynamic datatable (dynamic columns and rows) in my jsf page.

However, i need to display more than 1 table - vertically. How do I iterate in my list in order to display them?

thanks

Theres

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
    <ul>
        <ui:repeat value="#{someBean.items}" var="someCurrentItems">
            <li>
                <h:dataTable value="#{someCurrentItems}" var="currentItem"></h:dataTable>
            </li>
        </ui:repeat>
    </ul>
```

And if you want to get rid of the bulletins add this to your css file (you can give a more precise selector to the css if you will wrap the `ul` with some `div` with `id`...)

`ul { list-style-type: none; }`

Comment: Be careful, using `UIData` inside `UIRepeat` has some peculiar bugs in Mojarra.

Comment: @BalusC Ok, havent tried it myself... Is <c:forEach better in this specific case?

Comment: c:forEach is useful only if the model won't change on the same view because it's evaluated at view creation time.

Comment: it did not work :-( somehow the datatable inside the ui:repeat generates the same IDs probably the reason why it is not working.

Comment: what error msgs are you getting ? an unique id should be generated by the JSF (or a unique prefix/sufix in case you set your own id)

Comment: no error messages though. the datatable just doesn't show :-(

Answer (score 0):

Another example with more details:

```
<ul>
             <ui:repeat value="#{timeslipBean.usersSlips}" var="tabSlips" >
            <li>
             <p:dataTable id="timeslips" var="time" value="#{tabSlips.table}">
             <h2>
                 #{tabSlips.label} 
            </h2>                    
                  <p:column >
                   <f:facet name="header" >  
                               User  
                   </f:facet>  
                        <h:outputText value="#{time.user}"/>
                  </p:column>
                  <p:columns value="#{tabSlips.columns}" var="column" columnIndexVar="colIndex" styleClass="#{time.times[colIndex].festivo ? 'festivo' : null}">  
                         <f:facet name="header">  
                               #{column.header}  
                        </f:facet>  
                        <h:outputText value="#{time.times[colIndex].hours}" styleClass="#{time.times[colIndex].style}"/>
                   </p:columns> 
              </p:dataTable>    
            </li>
        </ui:repeat>
    </ul>
```